# Best-case complexity for an unsuccessfull search in a binary search tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Since i wasn't able to find an answer to this question:

What is the best-case complexity for an unsuccessful search within an unbalanced binary search tree in big-theta notation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand the question correctly and if you are asked about the amortized complexity or specific best-case.

For a specific case, then it will be `O(1)` for the best-case:

Imagine an unbalanced tree with root holding the value of `X`, with large left subtree (values smaller than `X`), but empty right subtree (no values larger than `X`).

Now, if you try to find any value larger than `X` (good case), you will realize that there is no such value just by visiting the root.

Comment: Unfortunately, i cannot tell what is the exactly meaning of "best-case". I would refer to it as "under best possible conditions", ie a specific case, so your answer is perfect, since i had the same in mind. Thanks!

Comment: Nitpicking: OP asked for big-theta notation, not big-O  ;)

Answer (score 1):

If the size of left tree is `N1` and the right tree is `N2`, the best case complexity is `Theta(min(log(N1), log(N2)) + 1)` (Notice that `N1 + N2 = N`).